# Connect to 10 mysql databases and run only run while wiht data from all

Tags: php, mysql

I try to connect 10 identical mysql databases to print them all in a nice straight line.

Is there anybody here that can give me an example of how this should work?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "***";
$password = "***";

$v1 = "wp282";
$v2 = "wp111";
$v3 = "wp72";
$v4 = "wp193";
$v5 = "wp555";
$v6 = "wp366";
$v7 = "wp74";
$v8 = "wp721";
$v9 = "wp924";
$v10 = "wp253";

$conn =   mysqli_connect($servername, $username1, $password, $v1 "v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10");
$query100 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wpd2_posts` where post_status='wc-processing' or post_status='wc-completed' or post_status='wc-failed' order by post_date DESC LIMIT $sidenr2,50") or die(mysqli_error($conn));   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query100))         
{
   echo $row['ID'];
}
```

Comment: How this should work is you shouldn't have 10 identical databases.

Comment: well I for one don't see where `$sidenr2` is defined; question's unclear in that respect

Comment: This just smells like bad database design to me.

Comment: Please consider changing your databases design. Otherwise, you can use [mysqli::slect_db](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.select-db.php) to switch between databases.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a strange request, but of course it can be done.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "***";
$password = "***";

$databases = array("wp282","wp111","wp72","wp193","wp555",
                    "wp366","wp74","wp721","wp924","wp253");

foreach ( $databases as $database ) {
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username1, $password, $database);

    $result = $con->query($con, "SELECT * 
                                    FROM `wpd2_posts` 
                                    where post_status='wc-processing' 
                                    or post_status='wc-completed' 
                                    or post_status='wc-failed' 
                                    order by post_date DESC 
                                    LIMIT $sidenr2,50") 
                    or die($con->error);   

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['ID'] . ' ';
    }
    $con->close();
}
```

> I dont see where `$sidenr2` comes from by the way

Comment: pstt.. you've got a typo when you define the `mysqli` object, it should be `$con` and not `$conn` :)

Comment: @TobiasF. Thank you sir

Comment: It was a mistake I did not get it removed before I posted, thanks for your reply I'm trying with it now :)

Comment: the page its blank :( there is a fail here   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

Comment: Sorry, spelling error. I spelt `$con` as `$conn` Fixed now

Comment: sorry, but the page its still blank :(